# Removing empty structure fields Matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, field

I'm facing the following problem: I have an array of structures like:

```
A.B(1,1).x = 'string'
A.B(1,1).y = 12
A.B(1,2).x = []
A.B(1,2).y = []
A.B(1,3).x = 'string2'
A.B(1,3).y = 4
```

And I would like to remove the empty 2. row from this structure, so that in the end I get fields for (1,1) and (1,3). 
I was trying to convert to cells, remove and then back to structure, but this way I had to retype names of fields.
How is it possible to do it? Can it be done without conversion from structures?

tia!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop or [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to determine which array elements are empty:

```
empty_elems = arrayfun(@(s) isempty(s.x) & isempty(s.y),A.B)
```

returns: `[0 1 0]`

or

```
empty_elems = arrayfun(@(s) all(structfun(@isempty,s)), A.B);
```

which checks if all fields are empty (use [any](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) instead of [all](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) to check if any element is empty instead of all).

Then remove them using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html):

```
A.B(empty_elems) = [];
```

Full solution to your problem in comments:

```
% find array elements that have all fields empty:
empty_elems = arrayfun(@(s) all(structfun(@isempty,s)), A.B);

% copy non-empty elements to a new array `C`:
C = A.B(~empty_elems);

% find elements of C that have y field >3
gt3_elems = arrayfun(@(s) s.y<3,C);

% delete those form C:
C(gt3_elems) = [];
```

execute this code step by step and analyze the intermediary variables to understand what's happening. It should be fairly clear.

Comment: what if I had much more fields like x,y,z etc. is there an efficient way to write this condition? because for just one condition isempty(s.x) it does not remove empty fields

Comment: maybe [structfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html) is applicable...

Comment: actually I was thinking about the following, that I have at first A.B the whole with data. then i apply a condition for A.B.().y > 3 and if so save in a new structure, from which I got this empty A.B.(1,2) (let's say A.B.(1,2).y = 2). is there maybe a better way to avoid the empty fields in the structure at once?

Comment: problem is comparing a number with an empty field will yield an empty result. I suggest first filtering the empty ones out, and then applying your condition.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well, but if so, then .. empty fields are the effect of applying my condition. Before all the fields had values, and due to the fact 2<3 I got empty fields.

Comment: Can you please update your question^^ to what your dealing with now, with relevant code and example input/output? It's not clear from your comments what you're getting at..

Comment: yes sure, sorry :)
my totally initial structure:
A.B(1,1).x = 'string'
A.B(1,1).y = 12
A.B(1,2).x = 'string3'
A.B(1,2).y = 2
A.B(1,3).x = 'string2'
A.B(1,3).y = 4
objective: delete columns in A structure, where A.B().y < 3.
output after the condition: A.B(1,2) is empty.
So I want either to know how to remove the empty fields (I'm trying with structfun as you recommended, but sorry I'm beginner and nowhere I can find any good example for this particular usage of structfun :( )
or I want to have at once removed field A.B(1,2) during the condition ...< 3.

Comment: thanks, now I know how to combine arrayfun and structfun, rest is fully clear, perfect!